# Linea de tiempo traspasa el menu de navegacion

Tags: html, css

Estoy construyendo mi propia pagina web, y planeaba colocar una timeline, he investigado y encontrado una que quiero tomar como modelo sin embargo debe de tener algo en su codigo que no consigo ver y que me esta fastidiando la barra del menu pues al hacer scroll hacia abajo, la timeline se superpone al menu, ¿sabeis que puede estar ocurriendo? no me pasa eso con el resto de componentes que he creado, os adjunto el codigo de la timeline, si es necesario aportar mi codigo de la barra de menu lo adjunto también sin problemas. Un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
/* Media Queries */

@mixin mq-xs {
    @media (min-width: 320px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
  
  @mixin mq-sm {
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
  
  @mixin mq-md {
    @media (min-width: 720px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
  
  @mixin mq-lg {
    @media (min-width: 1000px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
  
  $background: #f7f7f7;
  $box-shadow: 0px 1px 22px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  $border: 1px solid rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.4);
  $items: 5;
  $rows: ceil($items/2);
  
  /* Card sizing */
  
  $card-height: 400px;
  $card-width: 450px;
  $inner-margin: 15px;
  $number-size: 35px;
  $stagger: 180px;
  $outer-margin: 90px;
  $marker-size: 9px;
  
  /* Colors */
  
  $steps: #46b8e9;
  $colors: #46b8e9,
  #3ee9d1,
  #ce43eb,
  #4d92eb;
  $timeline: #bdbdbd;
  
  /* Calculations */
  
  $container-height: $rows * ($card-height + $outer-margin) + $stagger;
  $container-width: $card-width*2 + $outer-margin*3;
  $head-height: $number-size + 50;
  $body-height: $card-height - $head-height;
  $marker-dist: $card-width + $outer-margin/2 - $marker-size/2;
  
  /* Placeholders */
  
  @include mq-lg {
    %arrow {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-top: 15px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    }
    %marker {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      width: $marker-size;
      height: $marker-size;
      background-color: $timeline;
      border-radius: $marker-size;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 8px $background;
    }
  }
  
  
  /* Some Cool Stuff */
  
  $counter: $items - $rows + 2;
  @for $i from 1 through $rows {
    .demo-card:nth-child(#{$i*2-1})   { order: $i }
    .demo-card:nth-child(#{$i*2})     { order: $counter }
    $counter: $counter + 1;
  }
  
  /* Border Box */
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  /* Fonts */
  
  body {
    font-family: Roboto;
  }
  
  #timeline {
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: $background;
    border-top: $border;
    border-bottom: $border;
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 3rem;
      font-weight: 200;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    p.leader {
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 90%;
      margin: auto;
      margin-bottom: 45px;
    }
    .demo-card-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
      @include mq-lg {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        width: $container-width;
        height: $container-height;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      &::after {
        z-index: 1;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        border-left: $border;
        @include mq-lg {
          border-left: 1px solid $timeline;
        }
      }
    }
    .demo-card {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      margin: 10px auto 80px;
      max-width: 94%;
      z-index: 2;
      @include mq-sm {
        max-width: 60%;
        box-shadow: $box-shadow;
      }
      @include mq-md {
        max-width: 40%;
      }
      @include mq-lg {
        max-width: $card-width;
        height: $card-height;
        margin: $outer-margin;
        margin-top: $outer-margin/2;
        margin-bottom: $outer-margin/2;
        &:nth-child(odd) {
          margin-right: $outer-margin/2;
          .head::after {
            @extend %arrow;
            border-left-width: 15px;
            border-left-style: solid;
            left: 100%;
          }
          .head::before {
            @extend %marker;
            left: $marker-dist + 1;
          }
        }
        &:nth-child(even) {
          margin-left: $outer-margin/2;
          .head::after {
            @extend %arrow;
            border-right-width: 15px;
            border-right-style: solid;
            right: 100%;
          }
          .head::before {
            @extend %marker;
            right: $marker-dist - 1;
          }
        }
        &:nth-child(2) {
          margin-top: $stagger;
        }
      }
      .head {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 400;
        .number-box {
          display: inline;
          float: left;
          margin: $inner-margin;
          padding: 10px;
          font-size: $number-size;
          line-height: $number-size;
          font-weight: 600;
          background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
        }
        h2 {
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-size: 1.3rem;
          font-weight: inherit;
          letter-spacing: 2px;
          margin: 0;
          padding-bottom: 6px;
          line-height: 1rem;
          @include mq-sm {
            font-size: 165%;
            line-height: 1.2rem;
          }
          span {
            display: block;
            font-size: 0.6rem;
            margin: 0;
            @include mq-sm {
              font-size: 0.8rem;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .body {
        background: #fff;
        border: $border;
        border-top: 0;
        padding: $inner-margin;
        @include mq-lg {
          height: $body-height;
        }
        p {
          font-size: 14px;
          line-height: 18px;
          margin-bottom: $inner-margin;
        }
        img {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
      @for $i from 1 through $items {
        &--step#{$i} {
          $color: nth($colors, ((($i - 1) % 4) + 1));
          background-color: $color;
          .head::after {
            border-color: $color;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<section id=timeline>
    <h1>A Flexbox Timeline</h1>
    <p class="leader">All cards must be the same height and width for space calculations on large screens.</p>
    <div class="demo-card-wrapper">
        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step1">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>01</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Technology</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step2">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>02</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Confidence</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step3">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>03</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Adaptation</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step4">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>04</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Consistency</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step5">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>05</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Conversion</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Toda pregunta relacionada con HTML, CSS y/o Javascript, debe ser reproducible en el sitio. Si tu CSS está hecho con un preprocesador debes agregar el css postprocesado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería bastar con aplicar `z-index` al menú y a la línea de tiempo. Si incluyes un número mayor para el encabezado, el timeline ya no debería superponerse, por ejemplo: `z-index: 2` y `z-index: 1`, respectivamente.